# After Update event not triggering for Text Box on an Access form

Tags: vba, ms-access

I'm trying to create a record set that compares a quantity value in the recordset to a Value in a temporary table that holds the most recent remaining quantity. I have the following code in the After Update of a text box, but it does not trigger. I want it to run after a value is entered into the text box. Is the code wrong or the location I'm putting it incorrect?

```
Private Sub txtQty_AfterUpdate()
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset

DoCmd.OpenQuery "qryQuantitySoFar"
Set rs = Forms!frmReceive!sfrmReceiveDetailEntry.Form.RecordsetClone
   With rs
      Do While Not rs.EOF

      If rs("Qty") > Nz(DLookup("[RemainingQty]", "tblQtySoFarTEMP", "[OrderDetailPK]= " & rs![OrderDetailFK])) Then
     MsgBox "The Quantity received is greater than the outstanding quantity? Would you like to update the original order quantity?"
     End If
       rs.MoveNext
      Loop
  End With
Set rs = Nothing
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Go to the design view of the form and select your ComboBox. Look at the Events tab of the Property Sheet. Next to After Update, make sure it says either txtQty_AfterUpdate or [Event Procedure]. Just because you have an appropriately named event handler in the code does not necessarily mean that the event handler is attached.

Comment: I have double checked to make sure, but i defiantly have Event procedures linked to the correct items.

Comment: @Aron.Ridgway If you double click on [Event Procedure] in that area of the Property Sheet, does it jump to the code you posted above? Are you sure it's not triggering (if you put a breakpoint on DoCmd.OpenQuery does it get there) ??

Comment: As @MarkBalhoff said: do the doubleclick. If you have moved the control e.g. from body to head of your form, these event-links can break.